# 5/2 is 2 but I'm getting the one in index 3

Tags: java

I have a linked list 1-2-3-4-5-6. I need to get 4. I have a method that inserts all in the array and calculate the middle. if there are two, I'm printing the second one. in my head the method(I have on my text book) prints 3 but when I actually run it I get 4(as the text book indicates)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListNode x = new ListNode(1);


    ListNode y = new ListNode(2,x);
    ListNode a = new ListNode(3, y);
    ListNode b = new ListNode(4, a);
    ListNode c = new ListNode(5, b);
    ListNode d = new ListNode(6, c);

    ListNode r= middleNode(d);
    System.out.println(r.val);

}
public static ListNode middleNode(ListNode head) {
    ListNode[] A = new ListNode[100];
    int t = 0;
    while (head.next != null) {
        A[t++] = head;
        head = head.next;
    }
    return A[5 / 2];

}
A[0] = 1 
A[1] = 2
A[2] = 3
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 5
A[5] = 6 

A[t] =5 t being 5
thus t/2 = 2. so should print 3.
```

Comment: You should try stepping through it with a debugger and see where your expectation diverges from what actually happens

Comment: @Buddy good tip only if i knowo how. i'll look into it. thank you

Comment: What is `ListNode`... Please provide some code about it so we can help in coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListNode x = new ListNode(1);
ListNode y = new ListNode(2, x);
ListNode a = new ListNode(3, y);
ListNode b = new ListNode(4, a);
ListNode c = new ListNode(5, b);
ListNode d = new ListNode(6, c);
```

After you add all the nodes, then your LinkedList will be like this.

```
Head d -> c -> b -> a -> y -> x Tail
```

you are passing the head into the while loop to iterate.
so your loop should start with the head and add the values into the same order as you already added.

after you finish your while loop your `A` node should look like this.

```
A[0] - d
A[1] - c
A[2] - b
A[3] - a
A[4] - y
```

You can't get `A[5]` and `x` node because `x` node `next` has a null value and your condition is `while(head.next()!=null)`

finally if you return `A[5 / 2]` then you will get `A[2]` which contains `b` node.

when you print `r.val` you will get `b` node value `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Array `A` actually looks like this at the end (you can print it and check):

```
A[0] - 6
A[1] - 5
A[2] - 4
A[3] - 3
A[4] - 2
```

This is because you're passing `d` to `middleNode()` which has value 6. So 6 is the first element, then 5, then 4, and so on...

Lastly, in your while loop you're checking `while (head.next != null)` which is false for node `x` which has value 1. So value 1 is never inserted into the array (which is fine).

So at the end, your `t` has value 5, and so `t/2 = 2` (because of integer division) and you end up with `A[2] = 4`

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop you have reversed your nodes. So after reversing in the index 2 you have 4.